# All of a sudden started getting "Could Not Run The `Identify` Command. Please Install ImageMagick."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, rmagick

I've had ImageMagick, RMagick, & PaperClip working properly with everything setup including the config `Paperclip.options[:command_path]` in `production.rb` file.

All of a sudden I've started getting the following error:

```
Could Not Run The `Identify` Command. Please Install ImageMagick.
```

I've tried everything. I've reinstalled ImageMagick, etc. but no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm getting the same error too, were you able to resolve it?

Comment: If you use [brew](http://brew.sh/), you can easily install imagemagick by running `brew update`,`brew install imagemagick `.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to change the files `production.rb` and `development.rb` which are in:

**config/environments**:

```
# Paperclip config:
Paperclip.options[:image_magick_path] = "/opt/ImageMagick/bin"
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/opt/ImageMagick/bin"
```

Just add those two lines just before the last line and restart the server.

In MacOSX system, if you are using another location, just put the right PATH there.

Comment: Closing quote in 2nd line should be  ", but the minimum edit character does not allow to include the edit.

Comment: you are right @malditojavi, I just changed that. thanks

Comment: @Tanuj sorry I have not tried it yet in Linux, but it should work, just be sure that the path is the correct one. cheers

Answer (score 40):

From a terminal, run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Comment: The OP stated he already reinstalled ImageMagick, further there is no way of knowing he is on a Debian based operation system.

Answer (score 19):

For Mac users: just run the command `brew install imagemagick`.

Answer (score 14):

You can type

`which convert` and `which identify`

to check whether imagemagick is installed properly.

In my case, `which convert` returns `/usr/local/bin/convert` but `identify not found`.

I used `brew install imagemagick` before, so I run it again and return `imagemagick already installed, it's just not linked`.

Finally got the point, `brew link imagemagick`(or `brew link --overwrite imagemagick`)

Don't forget to add the `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"` to your `config/environment.rb` file.

Answer (score 11):

I had a same issue. This is what worked for me. From terminal, first:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue, when I had started rails server from my rubymine ide. It seems it does not load your .zshrc (in my case, could also be valid for .bashrc). So some environment variables that make imagemagick work with dvm were not set. For example:

```
export PATH=$HOME/local/imagemagick/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/local/imagemagick/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Once I restarted from my terminal, the error was gone.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. It was caused by https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1709

Comment: Thanks a ton for linking to this issue, I was running into this too. For Googlers' sake: in my case ImageMagick was installed and Paperclip integrated with it properly on a small scale, but when running jobs in a multi-threaded environment like Sidekiq, after a few hundred jobs suddenly Paperclip would "forget" where to find ImageMagick, and all jobs after that would fail. This was fixed in version 4.2.1 so upgrading should resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved this issue:

```
sudo apt install imagemagick
```

Answer (score 1):

For Cent OS users:

```
 sudo  yum install ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel
```

will do the job