# Paperclip - Rails Could not run the `identify` command. Please install ImageMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, imagemagick, paperclip

I have already tried brew install imagemagick as well as adding the gem to my gem file on my rails app but nothing works. any ideas? I have used paperclip before but never had this issue till now.

I have also tried this solution but it doesn't work either.

[All of a sudden started getting "Could Not Run The `Identify` Command. Please Install ImageMagick."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720994/all-of-a-sudden-started-getting-could-not-run-the-identify-command-please-in)

Comment: Did you try adding the `Paperclip.options.merge!(:command_path => "/usr/bin")` line in the production.rb file instead of `/usr/ImageMagick/bin` ?

Comment: Yes and that did not work either unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it running brew update, then installing imagemagick and finding out the route that I am supposed to put in my production.rb file running which convert on terminal!